# How to filter a dictionary by value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Newbie question here, so please bear with me.

Let's say I have a dictionary looking like this:

```
a = {"2323232838": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
     "2323221383": ("second/dir", "foo.txt"),
     "3434221": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
     "32232334": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
     "324234324": ("third/dir", "dog.txt")}
```

I want all values that are equal to each other to be moved into another dictionary.

```
matched = {"2323232838": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
           "3434221":    ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
           "32232334":   ("first/dir", "hello.txt")}
```

And the remaining unmatched items should be looking like this:

```
remainder = {"2323221383": ("second/dir", "foo.txt"),
             "324234324":  ("third/dir", "dog.txt")}
```

Thanks in advance, and if you provide an example, please comment it as much as possible.

Comment: As the others have said, you simply can't have dictionaries like you give in your examples. You have multiple values of unique_id, dir and file, and that just isn't legal. Dictionary keys are unique.

Comment: OH! My bad, sorry about that, i will correct it.

Comment: Your correction now isn't even syntactically correct Python. Perhaps you could ask "How would I represent the following data in Python data structures?" and then describe your data.

Answer (score 10):

The code below will result in two variables, `matches` and `remainders`.  `matches` is an array of dictionaries, in which matching items from the original dictionary will have a corresponding element.  `remainder` will contain, as in your example, a dictionary containing all the unmatched items.

Note that in your example, there is only one set of matching values: `('first/dir', 'hello.txt')`.  If there were more than one set, each would have a corresponding entry in `matches`.

```
import itertools

# Original dict
a = {"2323232838": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
     "2323221383": ("second/dir", "foo.txt"),
     "3434221": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
     "32232334": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
     "324234324": ("third/dir", "dog.txt")}

# Convert dict to sorted list of items
a = sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])

# Group by value of tuple
groups = itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x:x[1])

# Pull out matching groups of items, and combine items   
# with no matches back into a single dictionary
remainder = []
matched   = []

for key, group in groups:
   group = list(group)
   if len(group) == 1:
      remainder.append( group[0] )
   else:
      matched.append( dict(group) )
else:
   remainder = dict(remainder)
```

Output:

```
>>> matched
[
  {
    '3434221':    ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'), 
    '2323232838': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'), 
    '32232334':   ('first/dir', 'hello.txt')
  }
]

>>> remainder
{
  '2323221383': ('second/dir', 'foo.txt'), 
  '324234324':  ('third/dir', 'dog.txt')
}
```

As a newbie, you're probably being introduced to a few unfamiliar concepts in the code above.  Here are some links:

Comment: nice. I can see now that i misunderstood the question with my answer.
Anyway, looks good to me :)

Comment: Thank you, i will need to read up on groups, but that's all good, thanks a million. Also thanks for editing my question!

Comment: Note, len(group) is 1 should read len(group) == 1. While the identity test ("is") works here in cPython due to small integer caching, it's a bad habit to get into.  You want an equality test.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is called an "Inverted Index" -- the distinct items are recorded just once with a list of keys.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = {"2323232838": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
...      "2323221383": ("second/dir", "foo.txt"),
...      "3434221": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
...      "32232334": ("first/dir", "hello.txt"),
...      "324234324": ("third/dir", "dog.txt")}
>>> invert = defaultdict( list )
>>> for key, value in a.items():
...     invert[value].append( key )
... 
>>> invert
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('first/dir', 'hello.txt'): ['3434221', '2323232838', '32232334'], ('second/dir', 'foo.txt'): ['2323221383'], ('third/dir', 'dog.txt'): ['324234324']})
```

The inverted dictionary has the original values associated with a list of 1 or more keys.

Now, to get your revised dictionaries from this.

Filtering:

```
>>> [ invert[multi] for multi in invert if len(invert[multi]) > 1 ]
[['3434221', '2323232838', '32232334']]
>>> [ invert[uni] for uni in invert if len(invert[uni]) == 1 ]
[['2323221383'], ['324234324']]
```

Expanding

```
>>> [ (i,multi) for multi in invert if len(invert[multi]) > 1 for i in invert[multi] ]
[('3434221', ('first/dir', 'hello.txt')), ('2323232838', ('first/dir', 'hello.txt')), ('32232334', ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'))]
>>> dict( (i,multi) for multi in invert if len(invert[multi]) > 1 for i in invert[multi] )
{'3434221': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'), '2323232838': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'), '32232334': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt')}
```

A similar (but simpler) treatment works for the items which occur once.

Comment: Huh, very simple, gotta use the python standard lib. more, thanks for this.

Comment: Ah, nice, too.
It's amazing what you can do with simple standard calls :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dictionary is no different from iterating over a list in python:

```
for key in dic:
    print("dic[%s] = %s" % (key, dic[key]))
```

This will print all of the keys and values of your dictionary.

Comment: While you're right, this was handled in the comments, and doesn't answer his question, which was deducible.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your unique id will be the key.
Probably not very beautiful, but returns a dict with your unique values:

```
>>> dict_ = {'1': ['first/dir', 'hello.txt'],
'3': ['first/dir', 'foo.txt'], 
'2': ['second/dir', 'foo.txt'], 
'4': ['second/dir', 'foo.txt']}  
>>> dict((v[0]+v[1],k) for k,v in dict_.iteritems())  
{'second/dir/foo.txt': '4', 'first/dir/hello.txt': '1', 'first/dir/foo.txt': '3'}
```

I've seen you updated your post:

```
>>> a
{'324234324': ('third/dir', 'dog.txt'), 
'2323221383': ('second/dir', 'foo.txt'), 
'3434221': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'), 
'2323232838': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt'), 
'32232334': ('first/dir', 'hello.txt')}
>>> dict((v[0]+"/"+v[1],k) for k,v in a.iteritems())
{'second/dir/foo.txt': '2323221383', 
'first/dir/hello.txt': '32232334', 
'third/dir/dog.txt': '324234324'}
```

Comment: that's not what OP has asked for at all.

Comment: As yours isn't, too.
The OP had some different version in the beginning which confused me.
Tryptichs version seems to be alright, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what value you want to filter out:

```
known_tuple = 'first/dir','hello.txt'
b = {k:v for k, v in a.items() if v == known_tuple}
```

then `a` would become:

```
a = dict(a.items() - b.items())
```

this is py3k notation, but I'm sure something similar can be implemented in legacy versions.
If you don't know what the `known_tuple` is, then you'd need to first find it out. for example like this:

```
c = list(a.values())
for i in set(c):
    c.remove(i)
known_tuple = c[0]
```

Comment: No, it can very well be "third/dir", "something.txt", i don't know.